# telethon bot и cron linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron, telethon

Если я пытаюсь запустить мой telethon скрипт вручную на удаленном сервере linux, то я единожды получаю запрос ввода кода подтверждения с моего аккаунта телеграм. Клиент запомнил сервер как новое устройство пользования аккаунтом и больше кода авторизации не запрашивает и скрипт выполняется в последующие разы без проблем и лишних запросов. Но как только я вешаю этот скрипт на планировщик задач cron строкой типа:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/my/parser.py >> /path/to/my/logfile.log
```

то я получаю следующие ошибки в мой логфайл:

[image: Логфайл]

Что в этом случае нужно делать? как его заставить выполняться через планировщик?

Comment: А точно ли его надо запускать через планировщик, а не через systemd как сервис?

Comment: Планировалась его работа как распланированная по времени примерно каждые раз в пол часа. Почему то сразу подумал что надо делать через крон. Такое можно сделать через systemd?

Comment: Задание крон от такого пользователя запускается?

Comment: Задание запускается от обычного пользователя, также пробовал и под рутом, ему без разницы, если вручную, авторизацию не просит хоть где, только единожды, а если из под крона то всегда требует

Answer (score 0):

Вобщем проблема решилась следующим образом, отказался от cron, через supervisorctl закинул свой скрипт как сервис, а планировщик задач сделал через библиотеку python schedule